# cannot create extension without superuser role

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to run unit tests in Django, and it creates a new database. The database has postgis extensions and when I regularly create the database, I use "CREATE ExTENSION postgis".

However, when I run tests, it gives me the following error:

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_project" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_project', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
DatabaseError: permission denied to create extension "postgis"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

The user has the Create DB privilege already, I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 with Postgis 2.0.

Comment: Database owner can create extensions.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

[The Django documentation on postgis has some information on setting up database user privileges](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/gis/testing/#obtaining-sufficient-privileges).

In the worst case you can create a new database superuser for PostgreSQL:

```
$ createuser --superuser <user_name>
```

or alter an existing database user's role:

```
postgres# ALTER ROLE <user_name> SUPERUSER;
```

Comment: You're application should not be running as superuser. I've provided a solution to this question.

Comment: @HarryMoreno I wrote this answer ages ago when working at an agency where the database lived on the same server as the web app and would be torn down at the end of a marketing campaign and touched no other user data. I agree in general though, all other projects I've worked on have proper permissions for users (but if you're just testing locally, why not go with a superuser :P)

Comment: totally understandable, I was just presenting the answer I would want if I was less experienced. Hopefully others benefit from us.

Answer (score 77):

Easiest way I found is to:

```
su postgres
psql
alter role user_name superuser;
#then create the extension as the user in a different screen
alter role user_name nosuperuser;
```

Basically give the user superuser powers for a short time, and create the extension. Then revoke the superuser powers.

You can also use `\connect user_name` to become that user and create the extension directly from the `postgres` user.

Comment: That makes sense, no sense in keeping the user with superuser privileges, reduces the attack surface. I like it!

Comment: however the attack could exist in that short instant of time

Answer (score 38):

Another way to solve this that is suggested in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#creating-a-spatial-database)

```
$ psql <db name>
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

you can log into a database as the superuser and create the extension once. The extension will then be available to your api's db user. When django executes `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis` postgres will not throw.

If you are seeing errors when migrating doublecheck you created the extension in the correct database, a sample sesssion

```
$ psql
=> \l            - list databases
=> \c <db name>  - connect to django db
=> create extension postgis;
```

you can verify the extension is installed if you see the table `spatial_ref_sys`

```
=> \dt
                   List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |  Owner
--------+----------------------------+-------+----------
 public | spatial_ref_sys            | table | postgres
```

for tests I recommend running them against a local dev database and granting the user superuser abilities like `> ALTER ROLE <user_name> SUPERUSER;`

Comment: I don't get it, the question specifically asks how to do this WITHOUT superuser privilege. So we can't "log into a database as the superuser".

Comment: @cglacet useful info is useful

Comment: I disagree, stackoverflow is supposed to be organized, being useful is not enough for an answer. Either it's not possible and the question (title) should be updated, or your answer (and all others) should be moved to a separate question (good practices with user privileges and extensions). As I don't know the answer I can't decide, but the current state look like a mess

Comment: I disagree with @cglacet, all the other options actually include making the app user a superuser, there is actually no solution on this page that doesn't require superuser privileges. At least with this solution you are not fiddling with the app users privileges and opening up a dangerous backdoor in the future.

Answer (score 23):

You can also install `postgis` to the `template1` database template which is inherited by default by all newly created database.

```sh
$ psql -U postgres -d template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

All new databases created from this point will have the `postgis` extension installed, including Django's test database, unless they specify a different template when creating a database.

If having `postgis` installed to all newly created databases is not desirable, you can create a new template, install `postgis` in it, and then have Django use this template when creating the test database.

```sh
$ createdb template_postgis;  # create a new database
$ psql -U postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';"  # make it a template
$ psql -U postgres -d template_postgis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"  # install postgis in it
```

Then in Django settings:

```py
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'TEST': {
            'TEMPLATE': 'template_postgis',
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I have similar problem with django-extensions reset_db. I decided to use your hint with template1 (and postgis installed in it). Thank you. I just want mention that I can in this situation create databases without postgis using: CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template0;

Comment: Are you sure that using TEMPLATE in the database dict works? I am trying it and not it's not working. Also, i couldn't find any docs on it.

Comment: Documentation for test template can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#template

Answer (score 10):

As of Postgres 13, some modules / extensions are considered "trusted", and can be installed by non-superusers who have `CREATE` privilege on the current database.

The trusted modules are: btree_gin, btree_gist, citext, cube, dict_int, fuzzystrmatch, hstore, intarray, isn, lo, ltree, pgcrypto, pg_trgm, seg, tablefunc, tcn, tsm_system_rows, tsm_system_time, unaccent, uuid-ossp

To check whether a given module is eligible, visit https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/contrib.html and select the module in question. If it is considered "trusted", the page will contain the sentence:

> This module is considered “trusted”, that is, it can be installed by non-superusers who have `CREATE` privilege on the current database.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand why a trusted extension was asking for superuser privileges, but it is because we use an older version

Answer (score 6):

A safe way to do this without delegating superuser privileges would be to access the database in which we are executing the query with a user with a superuser role such as postgres.

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql <db_name>

<db_name>#= CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS <your-extension>;
```

This way you don't expose security and you can believe the extension in the db.

GL

Comment: if you are inside a docker container! run 
`su -u postgres`
than
`psql`
than
`\c <db_name>`

and than write the CREATE EXTENSION command.