# How to allow create extension without superuser privilege?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I went through the question/answers [cannot create extension without superuser role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527806/cannot-create-extension-without-superuser-role) and other related, which tells that I cannot avoid that issue without being a superuser.

But I am working with an AWS server now, in which I am able to install extension `tablefunc` without being a superuser, but I cannot do the same on a new postgres server. I am attaching a screenshot here of the roles present in the AWS database, here you will see, role `pgadmin` is not a superuser (and also none of the role group it's attached to are superuser, though it doesn't matter anyhow), but I can create the extension with it.

[image]

I understand the other workarounds, but just need a clarification for this. How is it working in AWS and why can't I replicate the same on a new Postgres server.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure out the solution for this ? How is it possible to grant Create Extension privilege to a postgresql user.

Comment: @JWahba You can use an user which is superadmin. Or make an user superadmin temporarily and make it nosuperuser again after creating the extension. Please check the attached question and answer. (I didn't find any other solution yet)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to and can update the extension control file, do this:

```
echo 'superuser = false' >> /usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/pg_cron.control
```

That example is for `pg_cron` but the same approach should work for any extension.